# React-native, clear webview cookie?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cookies, webview

It's possible to clear react-native webview cookie? when I replace to other view and back and mount webview again, it looks like the cookie still exist in the webview..

greetings

Comment: There some module they create cookie and also clear them. https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm using libraries to handle it but Google always seems to be logged in still on Android although I can clear them on iOS to log the user out.

Comment: So, finally I've made a method on the server side (smth like logout) which force user autologin and cookie recreate. Without this, after clear component, the webview still had access to the previous user data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [react-native-cookies](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies) to manage your app cookies.

```
import CookieManager from 'react-native-cookies';
// clear cookies on webview will mount!
CookieManager.clearAll()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('CookieManager.clearAll =>', res);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use AsyncStorage which comes with react-native

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
AsyncStorage.setItem('token', user.token)
AsyncStorage.removeItem('token')
AsyncStorage.getItem('token', (ignore, result) => {})
```

Just be careful the getItem is a promise based functionality.

Then on component load check create an action/function that checks if the user has the authorization for it based on the above!